# Can't create project via SFTP with an AWS EC2 in PhpStorm (or any JetBrains IDE)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpstorm, sftp, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to clone my project on an EC2 machine, the SSH connection works well. But when I tried to clone the project via SFTP in the last step it throws me 'failed to collect files: Could not resolve file'. It's weird because it starts to collect the files, but in some point it just throw the error.

Don't really know why this happen. Any suggestion?

This are the steps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlnVy.jpg

This is the idea.log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vkC3uReqm7JUihDiJr4SM4vjVxXU0O-G/view?usp=share_link

Comment: 1) Enable extra logging in the IDE: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-deployment.html#f63b53d0 2) Try downloading the project again. 3) When it fails, check `idea.log` (`Help | Show Log in XXX`). It could be that you have a file there with a weird name that the IDE cannot process (e.g. that would make an invalid file name on your OS)

Comment: This is idea.log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vkC3uReqm7JUihDiJr4SM4vjVxXU0O-G/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Seems like all the errors  are 'Could not list the contents of folder "sftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute.amazonaws.com/projects/htr-laravel/resources/lang" '

Comment: I tried to exclude from the download with no success:
- docker-config-files
- node_modules
- vendor

Comment: Can you ZIP the file remotely and then download the archive and unpack it locally? It is so much faster... If I have to get a project from a remote, I would always to to do it this way. Downloading individual files is not for me...

Comment: I could... But the idea with this is do something like remote development. Basiclly have a folder always synced with the server.

Comment: I tried the 'remote development' beta feature, but it has a lot of bugs. So I decided go for the SFTP option.

Comment: *"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel is closed"* -- could be something with keep-alive timeout or something like that.

Comment: I'd suggest you use `Help | Contact Support...` where you can privately provide all required info (like the `idea.log` with the extra SFTP logs). JetBrains support better known their own product and may already know the solution.

Comment: As I see you have created the ticket already: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-72606

Comment: Yeah, also a request... Someone has to know what happen. I even connected to the ec2 via sftp command line and it works.